# firefox addon: download external url into string

Tags: string, url, firefox, firefox-addon, add-on

I need to download some external urls to a string in a firefox addon.

How can I access the content of external urls for parsing?

Answer (score 0):

To find out the url of the current tab in a firefox addon you can do:

```
var localString = gBrowser.currentURI.spec;
```

Then you can parse localString the way you want.